# CSS for the remaining viewport width based on viewport height

Tags: html, css, css-position, viewport

This is for tablet browsers, it uses dimensions relative to viewport width/height. Assume a Landscape orientation for simplicity.

I have two divs in a fullscreen container, like the image provided. They have `position:absolute;`

[image]

- The red one, I want it to always be an square, the biggest to fit the screen, so I use height 100% and width "100vh", that is, 100% of viewport height.
- The green one: I'd like it to cover the remaining width.

I want to know if it's possible **in pure CSS** to express the remaining width for the green div. You can use `top,left,bottom,right,width,height,::before,::after` but the div has to be absolutely positioned (no float, etc..)

```
.red {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.green {
  height: 100%;
  width: /* ???? */;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The green one: I'd like it to cover the remaining width.

You could use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to subtract the height from the width in order to get the remaining width:

```
width: calc(100vw - 100vh);
```

Working Example:

```css
.red {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #f00;
}

.green {
  height: 100vh;
  width: calc(100vw - 100vh);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

Comment: Oh yeah! Didn't know this was possible :) Gonna have a read about `calc`

Comment: Also never knew about `calc`. Awesome.